# How to list the currently loaded drivers in Android (command to know the running drivers)?

Tags: android, linux, linux-device-driver, android-kernel

I am new to Android Linux. I just wanted to know the command to get the list of drivers or modules loaded on the Android device (something like `lsmod` which we have for basic Linux flavors). I tried `ls /system/lib/modules`, this gives the list of loadable modules, where as I want to know the currently loaded modules.

Comment: Depending on if your device is rooted, `lsmod` should work just fine.

Comment: On my Pixel running the P developer preview `lsmod` runs, but shows an empty list. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi , One more thing which i noticed is lsmod works fine when i insert a module using insmod {Loadable modules in /system/lib/modules} . but where as without inserting the loadable modules lsmod doesn't give out any result . what does this indicate ? { I am working on a development board }

Answer (score 0):

After a quick check on my personal phone (Motorola G5) `lsmod` should work just fine:

```
cedric:/system/lib $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
wlan                 4445615  0
```

Though I might add this is not a rooted device. On another rooted device (whose output I can't post here) I was also able to see other additional modules e.g. graphics drivers. Your mileage will vary based on your device and whether or not you have root access.